# Why is Nmap failing to bind my source IP?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, nmap, spoofing

I was trying to perform a Nmap scan using this IP spoofing command:

```
nmap -e eth0 -S 1.2.3.4 192.168.200.130
```

where `1.2.3.4` is the source IP that I want to use and `192.168.200.130` is the IP address of my metasploitable machine

but I keep on getting this error:

```
NSOCK ERROR [0.1190s] mksock_bind_addr(): Bind to 1.2.3.4:0 failed
(IOD #1): Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

I can say that the IP spoofing is not working because I tried to verify it on wire-shark.

From the attached picture, it can be clearly seen that the system is still using the original IP address of the kali machine instead of `1.2.3.4`:

[image: attached picture]

How do I get around this problem? I don't seem to find a clear solution anywhere. I know the command works because I was trying to follow a tutorial.

Comment: @Gantendo Same error. Just tried it.

Comment: So does the system have this IP? You cannot use it otherwise.

Comment: @DanielB The system doesn't have that IP but thats the whole point of using -S, isn't it?

Comment: Yes and no. Did you read the manual on this option?

Comment: Yes I did, it says that in order to use the -S option, you also need to specify the interface name, which I have done.

Comment: @DanielB I just need to perform a nmap scan without disclosing my real IP. Is there another way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why this cannot work on multiple levels.

First:
You do not specify `-Pn`, as recommended in the manual. Then, you are trying to use a TCP scan type (the default, `-sS`). Furthermore, your PC does not own the IP address, which means you need raw sockets. It is unclear whether you used `sudo` or were *root* when running the command.

Second:
If you spoof the source address, response traffic will not come back to your PC. It will go to the selected spoofed address (1.2.3.4). This means you cannot *scan* targets but at best harass them. This is also mentioned in the manual. Even if you selected another address on the same network, I doubt nmap would participate in ARP/NDP.

Spoofed addresses can only work within certain requirements (ie. where you are in a position to capture the response traffic somehow, e.g. using a switch mirror port or the like).

Third:
Across routers or even on the internet, this would doubly not work: The router would not know where to direct the response traffic and simply discard it. Routers may also have strict requirements about source addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I still don't get why it's working for this guy? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsuGFMloIBU&ab_channel=CyberSecuritySimplified

Comment: In the video, the VM running nmap could be the router (default gateway) for the other VM. There is unfortunately really no way to tell.